# Is it possible to delete messages of a deleted user in Discord app?

Tags: user-interface, discord

I am a Discord moderator of some chat room and my friend asked me yesterday if you can delete the messages of a deleted user. Is that possible? I have never had a deleted user in my chat room so I wasn't sure on what to answer. I know that you can delete a message of a non-deleted member of your chat room if it doesn't follow the rules of the chat room.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's definitely possible.

If it wasn't, abusing it would be very easy - people could join servers, spam worst possible messages and then delete their accounts.

You can either delete the messages directly:
[image: Direct deletion]
or use their ID with certain bots like Dyno to purge all messages, as Discord itself doesn't seem to support purging by ID.